# How to use ffmpeg in a python function

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg

I have tried to use a ffmpeg to extract an audio from a video file and this is my code

```
import io
import os
import subprocess

def extract_audio(video,output):
    command = "ffmpeg -i '{video}' -ac 1  -f flac -vn '{output}'"
    subprocess.call(command,shell=True)

extract_audio('dm.MOV','dm-new.flac')
```

And I got no error after compiled. By doing this I should get a new file which is 'dm-new.flac'. But there is no such a flac file created after I compile the script. I think there are something wrong with the syntax or something in the variable 'command' which I have no idea to fix this. My question here is how can I use ffmpeg in a python function base on this code?

By the way, I knew that I could just use ffmpeg without writing a function. But I really need to write in in a function. Thank you

Comment: Does it work for you if you put it in a script outside of python?

Comment: Yeah it work if I don't use a function

Comment: `c3 = "ffmpeg -i dm.mov -ac 1  -f flac -vn testdm.flac"
subprocess.call(c3, shell=True)`  like this

Comment: are you inputting strings into the arguments of the function? Do you think you therefore have extra quotes around the arguments in the script? just a guess. I think your arguments may not be properly formatted going into the script

Comment: You should try using format on your command variable, to change value for video and output to: dm.MOV and dm-new.flac.

Comment: I tried to delete the extra quote around the argument but it still the same

Comment: even with this I still think you need no quote at all in the script string, and I suspect you're still getting one quote, but again this is just a guess

Comment: @boandriy I know that it work on that way. But my problem here is that if I just want to be able to write an argument like video, output in the ffpeg script

Comment: @kevinkayaks `command = 'ffmpeg -i {video} -ac 1  -f flac -vn {output}'
`  This is what I meant but it didn't work

Comment: All of the answers below are worked. Thank you guy so much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
import io
import os
import subprocess

def extract_audio(video,output):
    command = "ffmpeg -i {video} -ac 1  -f flac -vn {output}".format(video=video, output=output)
    subprocess.call(command,shell=True)

extract_audio('dm.MOV','dm-new.flac')
```

I think you were trying to reference two variables inside a string but did not tell Python that you should replace 'video' and 'output' with their corresponding variables. `.format()` allows you to reference the variables that you refer to in a string.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Add one character (`f`) to solve it (over python 3.6):

```
import subprocess
def extract_audio(video,output):
    command = f"ffmpeg -i '{video}' -ac 1  -f flac -vn '{output}'"
    subprocess.call(command,shell=True)

extract_audio('dm.MOV','dm-new.flac')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is it.

```
import io
import subprocess
def extract_audio(video,output):
    command = "ffmpeg -i {} -ac 1  -f flac -vn {}".format(video,output)
    subprocess.call(command,shell=True)

extract_audio('dm.MOV','dm-new.flac')
```

Comment: Interesting... accepted answer but written two minutes after mine... win some, lose some!

Comment: it's different!

Comment: Works fine for me - have you tested?

Comment: oh, I thought you had extra quotes. alright, kudos!

Answer (score 1):

I belive this should work:

```
import io
import os
import subprocess

def extract_audio(video,output):
    command = "ffmpeg -i {} -ac 1  -f flac -vn {}".format(video, output)
    subprocess.call(command,shell=True)

extract_audio('dm.MOV','dm-new.flac')
```