# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffmpeg' on Spyder although ffmpeg is installed on Anaconda navigator

Tags: python, ffmpeg, anaconda, spyder

ffmpeg is installed on Anaconda Navigator (in `base(root)` environment), but when I run `import ffmpeg`, I got this error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffmpeg'
```

Why is this module not found and how can I fix this?

[image: screenshot of Anaconda Navigator]

Comment: I installed ffmpeg with `pip install python-ffmpeg` on Anaconda Prompt and now I can import it on Spyder.

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'input'` showed up, so I uninstalled `python-ffmpeg` and installed `ffmpeg-python` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install the ffmpeg-python module to the environment:

```
pip install ffmpeg-python
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg-python
```

from there `import ffmpeg` statements when using the environment should work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert but [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/conda-forge/ffmpeg-feedstock/issues/57) explains that anaconda installs FFmpeg as a script that can be run but not as a package you can `import`. As such you need to note the path of the FFmpeg.exe for your anaconda environment + build the commands and pass them to the `subprocess` module, which you do need to import. So, building on a SO questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197883/how-to-use-ffmpeg-in-a-python-function), to compress a video (for example), a Windows command in python might look something like:

```
import subprocess
pathFFmpeg = r'C:\Users\YOURNAME\anaconda3\envs\ENVNAME\Scripts\ffmpeg.exe'
pathInput = r'C:\Videos\mybigvideo.mp4'
pathOutput = r'C:\Videos\mysmallervideo.mp4'
commands_list = [
    pathFFmpeg,
    "-i", pathInput,
    "-c:v", "libx265",
    "-preset", "fast",
    "-crf", "22",
    "-c:a", "aac",
    "-b:a", "196k",
    "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", pathOutput
    ]    
results = subprocess.run(commands_list)
if results.returncode==0:
    print ("FFmpeg Script Ran Successfully")
else:
    print ("There was an error running your FFmpeg script")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to use pip command to install FFmpeg as a python library

```
pip install ffmpeg
```