# extraction frames from video using python code

Tags: python

I have tried to extract video frames using python but it shows an error like "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffmpeg'" can anyone have any solution?

Comment: Can you add your code which caused mentioned error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffmpeg' on Spyder although ffmpeg is installed on Anaconda navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68930093/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-ffmpeg-on-spyder-although-ffmpeg-is-insta)