# Merging videos using ffmpeg with overlapping time

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I want to input the audio files present in a local file and merge them with defnite overlap time in a dynamic way and that means overlap time i will be providing will change from one instance to another.I want to use ffmpeg command using python script
I have been using this ffmpeg command to merge two audios

ffmpeg -i sound.mp3 -i sound2.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]adelay=10000|10000[b]; [0][b]amix=2" audiomerged.mp3

|<---- 1st mp3 file -------------------->                       |
|                        <-----------2nd mp3 file ------------->|

result:
|<-----------------------(overlap 10 sec )--------------------->|

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: I don't see how this is connected to python? ffmpeg is a program on it's own not dependant on python whatsoever

Comment: i saw somewhere ffmpeg command can be written in python script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197883/how-to-use-ffmpeg-in-a-python-function i have referred  this

Comment: that's just calling commandline with the command, so you could do the same without python.

Comment: Thanks for replying basically, i want convert a ffmpeg command to a python script.

Comment: I want to do it in python because i want to use it in a dynamic way

Comment: that doesn't make sense. FFMPEG is not integrated in python, so any interaction you make with it will be through a console

Comment: yeah i am using Python subprocess module

Comment: that means the question still doesn't have anything to do with python, and it's just pure ffmpeg.

Comment: So, I have ffmpeg command for merging of multiple audios working in command line interface and i have to integrate this command to a python code. Since i can't use ffmpeg command directly in python code so, I want to convert this ffmpeg command to python script. this conversion part is the one which i am facing difficulty. I have tried using subprocess module unsucessfully.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486725/how-to-execute-a-command-prompt-command-from-python

Comment: Please clear you question with separated paragraphs and use markdown fences to make clear where your command lines are, and separated from the question context.