# Try to execute ffmpeg in python - subtitles error

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I try to exectute :
./ffmpeg.exe -i "video.mkv" -vf subtitles="video.mkv" "video.mp4"
This command works fine

But not in my python code

```
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess
import os


ffmpeg = r"D:\Archives\ffmpeg.exe"
os.chdir(r"D:\temp\video")
videos = Path(".")

for file_mkv in videos.glob("*.mkv"):
    file_mp4 = file_mkv.with_suffix(".mp4")
    subprocess.run([ffmpeg, "-i", file_mkv, "-vf", f'subtitles="{file_mkv}"', file_mp4])
```

Error :
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0000020cb26222c0] Unable to open "video.mkv"
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000020cb715a380] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with args '"video.mkv"'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use ffmpeg in a python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197883/how-to-use-ffmpeg-in-a-python-function)

Answer (score 1):

change f'subtitles="{file_mkv}" to f"subtitles={file_mkv}" and it's works

```
subprocess.run([ffmpeg, "-i", file_mkv, "-vf", f"subtitles={file_mkv}", file_mp4])
```